# Should there be a "Duplicated off site" close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In some of the open source communities I am involved in we occasionally run into situations where a user will post the exact same issue in literally every place they can find - mailing lists, issue trackers, other Q&A boards and of course StackOverflow itself.

#### Example

As an example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880610/jena-jsonld-has-an-issue-while-translating-rdf-with-custom-datatype-to-jsonld) was also posted to a [mailing list](http://s.apache.org/7dy) and filed as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/issues/126) with the question being essentially identical in all cases (some venues have slightly more detail).

In my opinion this question isn't a particularly good fit for SO because:

- It is an incomplete question because it shows data and a stack trace but not the code to reproduce the issue
- It actually boils down to being a bug report on a specific project

So I have commented as such, linked the relevant duplicates and voted to close as Off Topic with a custom reason.

However this isn't the first time I've encountered similar behaviour and it makes me wonder whether we don't need a **duplicated off-site** close reason, especially in cases like this where the small community of developers of a specific project are much more likely to be able to provide a fix and a response then most people on SO.

#### Thoughts on Implementation

Closing as an off-site duplicate would require providing an external URI for the duplicate and in the close-review queue a tab should be used to display the off-site duplicate to other reviewers for consideration (similar to current duplicates behaviour).  Obviously there are spam and security issues to be careful about here so you may need the option to flag the off-site duplicate as inappropriate.

Duplicated off site could be limited to users with certain amounts of reputation or holding gold badges in relevant tags (similar to the gold badge dupe-hammer) in order to prevent over use.  So users would first have to have earned sufficient reputation to close normally (and perhaps even earned the gold close review badge) before then earning the further amount of reputation necessary to access the **duplicated off-site** functionality.

#### Question

So my question is do other people think this would be worth having or is this already sufficiently covered by just using custom close reasons on the occasions where this situation occurs?

Comment: No, questions should be on or off-topic on their own, regardless of where else they may have been posted.

Comment: If that was the case then 99.9% questions on here would be duplicates

Comment: @Stacker-flow Well yes most questions on SO are likely answered elsewhere as well, what sets SO apart is the enforcement of a specific Q&A format and the curation of the content

Comment: AFAIK one of the intents of SO is to be a top-of-mind place to go when you have a problem. I don't see a problem with a good answer existing here and somewhere else. Also whatever external resource you would point to may cease existing at random, which would kinda defeat the purpose of such a close reason.

Answer (score 13):

> - It is an incomplete question because it shows data and a stack trace but not the code to reproduce the issue
> - It actually boils down to being a bug report on a specific project

Those are both perfectly good reasons to close a question. There's no need to introduce another reason just because the question was also asked somewhere else. Information on other sites can be pulled in to one of the answers, or simply linked to in a comment.  Much (most?) of the information on Stack Overflow can be found somewhere else if you look hard enough, so I don't see that as a good reason to close questions.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of issues that immediately come to mind:

1. This would be greatly misused. It would likely become the go-to close reason for anything easily found on google.
2. The off-site resources can go away.
3. If a question is marked as "duplicate of <off-site-url>" then essentially SO is Google. It would be virtually the same end result to just delete the question and let people find the original via Google instead of a relay through SO.

Answer (score 6):

We can't and won't police people asking the same questions in different locations; they retain the right to ask the question anywhere they like. Questions here are on or off-topic here *by the content of the post alone*.

If a question does not contain enough information to reproduce the problem, close it as such. If the additional information is available elsewhere, the OP should add that to their question here.