# Should questions that are also posted in other Stackexchange sites be flagged/closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I've seen some questions (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690489/how-to-animate-stuff-with-animations-with-animate-css-and-jqury#29690489)) where people will just double post their question in other StackExchange sites such as Programmers StackExchange, CodeReview StackExchange, Android StackExchange, etc.

I feel having duplicates (even if they exist on other StackExchange sites) should be able to be marked duplicate but I'm not entirely sure if this is the case?

The closest question I could find similar to this was [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276672/should-there-be-a-duplicated-off-site-close-reason) question but it deals with sites outside of the StackExchange and I do not think it is exactly the same. I also found a question regarding [flagging migration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) but that's different because **the issue isn't the question doesn't belong here; the issue is that that the asker shouldn't just be posting his question everywhere to increase the probability of receiving an answer sooner**. Or maybe that's okay because you are asking different communities?

Apologies if there is a duplicate but I could not find one regarding this.

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a question is on-topic for a site then it should not be closed, no matter if it is a cross-post. If it is off-topic for a given StackExchange site then it should be closed or maybe migrated to the appropriate site first and then closed as a duplicate.

Questions that are on-topic on multiple sites are usually few, can't be on-topic for more than two or three sites.

Since each site may have a different userbase with distinct experience/skillset, the answers provided could be non-identical thus providing a diverse point of view (even though the question content was same).

That being said, the question should be tailored for that specific community. It should not be just a copy-paste because that is against StackExchange's policies and is considered abusive behavior.

Comment: It seems you are wrong according to @DavidPostill's question link.

Comment: @aug agreed but if you look at other answers and comments in the same post, they support my argument. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75012/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu#comment302240_64069

Comment: Ah I see. I guess the scenario I am talking about is wrong though according to the first comment in the answer you linked. Copy and pasting is bad.